# GitHub doesn't show lines count that changed by contributor in contributors list page

Tags: github

I guess it depends on the size of the repo? Is there a way to make it show the stats regardless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[image]

Make sure to add your feedback in the hope that GitHub will bring the stats back!

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) The same applies to quoted text.